# Enterprise Library ODP.NET call returns ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Tags: c#, oracle, enterprise-library, odp.net, enterprise-library-6

I have the following Oracle Stored Procedure:

```
PROCEDURE SP_ITEMEXISTS(pID IN NUMBER, pExists OUT CHAR) IS
BEGIN
        select CASE count(*) WHEN 0 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END into pExists from items where id = pID;
END SP_ITEMEXISTS;
```

I'm calling it from Enterprise Library 6.0 with ODP.NET with the following code:

```
public bool ItemExists(int itemID)
{
    string procedureName = "SP_ItemExists";
    var database = new DatabaseProviderFactory().CreateDefault();
    bool returnValue = false;

    using (OracleCommand command = (OracleCommand)database.GetStoredProcCommand(procedureName))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("pID", OracleDbType.Int32, itemID, ParameterDirection.Input);
            OracleParameter pExists = command.Parameters.Add("pExists", OracleDbType.Char, ParameterDirection.Output);

            database.ExecuteNonQuery(command);

            if (pExists.Value.ToString().ToUpper() == "Y")
                returnValue = true;
            else
                returnValue = false;
        }

    return returnValue;

}
```

I receive the following error:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Calling the Stored Procedure from Oracle SQL Developer works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be the same problem like here: [How to Convert Datetime to OracleTimeStamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522210/how-to-convert-datetime-to-oracletimestamp/20524107#20524107)

You must specify size of return value, i.e.

```
OracleParameter pExists = command.Parameters.Add("pExists", OracleDbType.Char, 1, null, ParameterDirection.Output);
```